# How to embed a file gist in an HTML file?

Tags: github, gist

I used to embed a gist file in the HTML using code such as the following:

```htm
<script src="https://gist.github.com/4577639.js?file=hello_world_addr.wsdl"></script>
```

This no longer works since all the files are shown and not the individual file. Anyone knows why this happening and how to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here you are good sir

```htm
<script
  src="https://gist.github.com/claudemamo/4577639.js?file=hello_world_addr.wsdl">
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Medium still doesn't support this approach for multi-file github gist :(